# HIGHCHARTS Moving image on mouseover/out event at the end series in live data

Tags: highcharts

I would like to add/remove an image using a button mouseover and mouseout events in the live streaming data.

Here What i tried was

```
 $("#Up")
  .mouseover(function() {
   var chart = $('#tv_chart_container').highcharts();
  data = chart.series[0].data;
  var test = data.length;
  var value = data[999].y;
  var x_value = data[999].x;
  chart.series[0].data[999].update({
    y:value,
    marker: {
      enabled:true,
      symbol: 'url(<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/graph_circle.png)'

    },

  });
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    console.log(value);
    var chart = $('#tv_chart_container').highcharts();
  data = chart.series[0].data;
  var test = data.length;
  var value = data[999].y;
  var x_value = data[999].x;
  chart.series[0].data[999].update({
    y:value,
    marker: {
      enabled:false,
    },

  });
  });
```

But with the help of above function. I can display the image only at the end and cant hide the same on mouseout event. Because Its a live streaming data. For Eg.When i use mouse over at the 999th series, It places a marker image and when i use mouse out at the less than 999th series. Cant hide the image. And at the same time the image should be a moving one along with the 999th series when i use mouseover.

Here is the sample image

[image]

Comment: Hi, So you would like to achieve something similar to this functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/8ankuh8s/3/ ? You can make this kind of chart using renderer.image instead of using point.marker.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thanks a lot . This is what i looked for.